# Is it OK to ask a META question just to get a hat?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

I've been playing along and earning hats. Is it O.K. to ask a META question with that specific goal in mind? I would think those of our group that aren't taking part would find it annoying.

Comment: Did I just ask for a hat? Yes. Yes, I did.

Comment: It's defnitely not ok for you, since your butter is way cooler than any hat

Comment: @MajorStackings - What you did there, I see it :P

Comment: Well played, sir.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it's not okay.

Or maybe it is. But it's not likely anyone will do anything about it...

Answer (score 12):

No it's not OK. Unless it was a real question with a meaningful answer. Like this one.

I feel a temporal paradox coming on...